# BGP No auto-summary and No synchronization configuration

Tags: bgp

This is what I understand from these

Auto-summary: Summarized routes will be advertised to their classful boundaries

Synchronization: iBGP will not advertise its routes to eBGP without learning IGP routes first

Anything you can add from these.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you understand the concepts but the words or phrases you used may cause confusion.

1. Auto-summary: a router summaries its locally-originated BGP networks to their classful boundaries. Also, all reditributed subnets (into BGP, if a router has) will be summarized to their classful boundaries into BGP table.
2. Synchronization: If your AS is a transit AS, synchronization prevents a BGP speaker from advertising a route to an EBGP peer until all routers within the speaker’s AS have learned about the route via an IGP.